# Primary color and accent from similar colors

Tags: color, google-material-design, palette

I am new to material design and still learning.

Is it a good idea to have the primary color and the accent from similar palettes, e.g Blue 500 and Light Blue A200? Or is the whole idea of the primary/accent to create enough contrast and you should be using colors that are really different?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the material rules behind accent colours but as a digital designer I prefer to subscribe to a mix of brand, aesthetics and colour theory.

I start with the clients brand colours and work out how they appear on screen. Look at contrasts and complimentaries. Each have their place in the usability. I create a colour page for the clients to talk them through how the brand colours work and always link this back to UX. If they are lacking in a colour for particular puprsoses e.g. a contrasting colour, then I talk them into adding another colour to their brand palette.

The next step is to take into consideration users physical eyesight.
If you are following accessibility guidelines then I wouldn't be using blue on blue. It doesn't have a high enough contrast for protanopia and deuteranopia colour blindness.

And for accessibility guidelines, these are issued by Governments. And published online. Here's an example of the Australian guidelines https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/

Comment: Accessibility guidelines primarily have to do with readability and usability. No one would be using the light blue for text color on the darker blue background or anything like that, so I don't think it really relates to the real question the OP is getting at

Answer (score 0):

I think doing like you said you are not following the right guidelines of the material design.
It's a good habit to use a primary and a secondary color and light and dark variants for each color that often are not more than two.
You can find more accurate answer [here](https://material.io/design/material-theming/overview.html#material-theming) and [here](https://material.io/design/color/applying-color-to-ui.html#top-bottom-app-bars)